# Кнопка поверх ListView

Tags: android, listview, button

Как в Layout задать расположение кнопки поверх ListView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.develop.nov.BooksDownloadActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_books_download">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/download"
        android:onClick="showResult"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Задайте высоту списка во весь экран. Или уточните вопрос

Comment: Убрал android:layout_above="@+id/button" и стала отображаться поверх ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context="ru.develop.nov.BooksDownloadActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_books_download">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

    <Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/download"
        android:onClick="showResult"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```